# How can I check if I still have Ubuntu as a second operating system? (Alongside Windows 10)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

About two years ago I installed Ubuntu as a requirement for an IT academy, but ever since I finished the academy course, I have been on my Windows constantly. I haven't gone onto my Ubuntu for almost a year. I used to be able to choose whether I log into Windows or Ubuntu whenever I would turn on or restart my PC, but it's been months since that option stopped appearing, and it just automatically goes straight to Windows. Is it possible I somehow lost Ubuntu because I wasn't using it for too long?

Comment: Losing for that reason no.

Comment: Windows updates have probably removed/disabled grub, maybe even messed up partition tables.  Ubuntu is still there and usually easiest fix is to boot into a Ubuntu installer USB and reinstall grub.